# django nonrel on gae not respecting model order when filtering results

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

When my query includes an order_by(...) I get the results in the expected order, however if I try to combine the order_by with a filter I get the results in the wrong order.

Is this something that isn't supported?

Comment: looks like the problem is is related to using filter(xxx__in = [..]) because that seems to break the order